# Applying strings and using them in if-else statements in java

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Whenever I run this program, everything runs fine until I get to the bottom where I'm supposed to type "y" or "n". I type "n" (without the parenthesis), and for some reason it continues to loop. Most likely, I'm improperly using. However, any help is fully appreciated! Thanks!

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class GuessTheNumberEC
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  int guess = 5;
  int randomNumber;
  int guessRepetition = 1;
  String yes = "y";
  String no = "n";
  String answer;

  randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 24 + 1);
  System.out.println(randomNumber);

  for(;;){

     for (int x = 1; x<=4; x++) {
        System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 - 25.");
        guess = reader.nextInt();

        if(guess == randomNumber) {
           System.out.println("Guess #" + guessRepetition + " is correct.");

           if(guessRepetition == 1) {
              System.out.println("Great, you guessed the number in " + guessRepetition + " try.");
              break;
           }
           else {
              System.out.println("Great, you guessed the number in " + guessRepetition + " tries.");
              break;
           }
        }  
        else if (guess > randomNumber) {
           System.out.println("Guess # " + guessRepetition + " is too high.");
           guessRepetition ++;


        } 
        else if (guess < randomNumber) {
           System.out.println("Guess # " + guessRepetition + " is too low.");
           guessRepetition ++;

        }
     }

     if (guess != randomNumber) 
     {
        System.out.println("The number was " + randomNumber + ".");
        System.out.println("You couldn't guess the number in 4 tries, so you lose.");
     }
     System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Press 'y' or 'n'");
     answer = reader.next();

     if (answer == no)
        break;
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
answer == no
```

to

```
answer.equals(no)
```

Why? Because the == operator will compare the two variables at a reference level. Your string "answer" will contain the same characters as your string "no" but they are different *objects*, and as such == will return false. equals() will test the content of the two Strings instead, and return true if they contain exactly the same characters (case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

Learn the difference between `==` and `.equals`.

`==` compares between raw values or object references, it's only going to be equal if the object references are the same.

`.equals` compares objects for their content, and it's what you should be using in this case.